# Iterate over an array of objects only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, iterated-function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

`allQuestions` is the array of objects, which role is providing the questions(`question`), the answers(`choices`) and the correct response(`correctAnswer`) for my app.

```
        var allQuestions = [{question: "If you were a super hero what powers would you have?",
            choices: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
            correctAnswer:0},

            {question: "Do you have a cherished childhood teddybear?",
                choices: ["e", "f", "g", "j"],
                correctAnswer:0},

            {question: "Whats your favourite non-alcoholic drink?",
                choices: ["i", "j", "k", "l"],
                correctAnswer:0},

            {question: "Are you religious?",
                choices: ["m", "n", "o", "p"],
                correctAnswer:0}];
```

Next, once my button, with `#next` id is clicked, the paragraph with id `#question` **should change his text with the next question** from the `allQuestions` array.

**The real result**? When I clicked on next button, the function iterates over all the questions and it showed the last one only.

I tried to use a solution from stackoverflow, setting a var `hasLooped` but doesn't work.

```
        $('#next').click(function(){
            //var hasLooped = false;
            $.each(allQuestions, function(key){

               // if(!hasLooped) {
                    $('#question').text(allQuestions[key].question);
               // }
               // hasLooped = true;
            })
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save index of question in a variable and increment it whenever `#next` is clicked.

Write this:

```
$(function () {
    var count = 0,
        len = allQuestions.length;
    $('#next').click(function () {
        if (count < len - 1) {
            count++;
            $('#question').text(allQuestions[count].question);
        } else {
            $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

[`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/wZ9yd/2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the current question somewhere externally and refer to that rather than the key passed to the each function as that will always loop through all and you'll see the last one.

```
var intNum = 1;

$('#next').click(function(){

    $('#question').text(allQuestions[intNum].question);
    intNum++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickCount = 0;
$('#next').click(function(){        
  $('#question').text(allQuestions[clickCount].question);       
  clickCount=(clickCount+1>9)?0:clickCount+1;
});
```

Comment: why `(clickCount+1>9)?0:clickCount+1;`?

Comment: Just to iterate over allQuestions array

Comment: `var MAX=10; clickCount=(clickCount+1)%MAX;` sounds more intuitive to me.

Comment: yeah. That way is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like global variables, you may try this:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    var counter = parseInt($("#next").attr("counter"));
    if (counter>=allQuestions.length){
        alert("No more questions!");
        return;
    }
    $('#question').text(allQuestions[counter].question);
    $("#next").attr("counter",counter+1);
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6BUz4/1/)